# Unit Testing $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a controller which has a method called results and inside has a $http.get API request.

Could someone please explain how to go about testing the $http.get request? I've looked at using $httpBackend but am unable to put together code that works.

Comment: How about `Jasmine`: http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html

Comment: @Hackerman: I currently have Karma/Jasmine running tests. My issue is that I'm not sure how to test that the API is being fired when I call my method "results".

Comment: Check out his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997638/testing-http-get-requests-in-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing AngularJS controller with $httpBackend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427968/unit-testing-angularjs-controller-with-httpbackend)